# is it bad to bring around a laptop with mechanical drive when it's ON and not SLEEP?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

How about when the laptop is ON and is not sleep, is it bad to move it slightly aside?

For example, I am using my laptop at a starbuck and waiting for my friend, he comes and gives me a set of meal. I then move over the laptop without closing the laptop.

Could it be bad to a mechanical hard drive laptop in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Mechanical harddrive works by having the read/write head "float" on a platter to read/write data. The disc spin at a high speed. When you make sudden, violent movement, the head could touch the platter and cause damage. When you put the harddrive to sleep, the head is "parked" on the side to prevent it from touching the platter by accident. I would definitely recommend putting the laptop to sleep before moving.

Having said that, modern laptops and harddrive have built in protection against drops and sudden movements. So you are most likely safe. But don't bet your data on that! If you see yourself doing it frequently, just spend $60-80 to upgrade your HDD to SSD. You will be rewarded with noticeable performance gain.

Comment: hi, always closing the laptop screen, putting it into sleep mode and bringing it around, is it safe enough for the hard drive and won't lead to damage? I am more concerned about the life of hardware, trying to keep it as perfect, reducing the cost. I am not so worried about data because I always backup